# Hetrobilayer charge density by using quantume espresso

Tags: vesta

When I want to visualize charge density in VESTA I got this error "**Number of data grids in the 3D data sets do not match each other" How can I fix this problem

Answer (score 3):

From [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Number-of-data-grids-not-match-with-each-other):

> The CHGCAR files have different values of NGX, NGY, and NGZ. So, you
> are seeing the error. You need to have all the three values same, so
> you can specify them in the INCAR before running the jobs. The error
> then should get eliminated.

I see that you have complained that one of the links in the answer does not work. However, you can reach the archived version of that page [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20181215063420/http://cms.mpi.univie.ac.at/vasp/vasp/NGX_NGY_NGZ_NGXF_NGYF_NGZF_tags.html). However, these are deprecated/obsolete links. You should visit the updated VASP manual. Corresponding webpage links from the update VASP manual are: [here](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/NGX) and [here](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/NGXF).

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Abdul Muhaymin... I am working on Quantum Espresso, not VSP..

Comment: @ahmedhassan a similar thing can be done in QE I believe but I am not sure. Try to set `nx, ny, nz` the same if you have used the [QE post-processing module](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_PP.html). If it doesn't help, you can post a new question with additional info such as how you ran your QE calculation and how you obtained the charge density file (corresponding input files).

Comment: @Abdul Muhaymin Thank you for replying. Do you mean Nx, Ny, and Nz should be the same value such as Nx=Ny=Nz= 128? is it

Comment: @ahmedhassan yes, it seems so from the aforementioned sources. But I have never tried it for myself so cannot say anything for sure.

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin Thank you, brother, I really appreciate your comments